# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to load a 2d object array in intelij

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have made a class with getter and setter methods, setting up one object was easy but as soon as I tried to set array it started giving me `NullPointerException`.

this is a function that I tried using to fill up the list:

```
public static void LoadKorisnike (int id, String ime, String prezime, String sifra){
    ListaKorisnika[id].setSifra(sifra);
    ListaKorisnika[id].setUserName(ime+prezime+Integer.toString(id));
    ListaKorisnika[id].setIme(ime);
    ListaKorisnika[id].setPrezime(prezime);
};
```

and here is the example of a set method:

```
public void setIme(String ime) {
    Ime = ime;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lacking a bunch of context, but most likely you haven't inserted a object at [id] yet, that's why you get a nullpointer exception there. Try first calling

```
ListaKorisnika[id] = new YourClass();
```

before you start with the setters.